# Only Collect in Store for Certain Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, shipping, shipping-methods, shopping-cart

I am on Magento 1.9.2 CE.

I have setup a Shipping method called "Collect in Store". There are some products which cannot be shipped and need to collected in person, Can anyone suggest any extension or some sort of starting point for creating an extension. For Example: if the Cart has a product from category Id 35 , then only display the "Collect in Store Method". Not any other

Many Thanks for you help.

Comment: Do you need to add an additional method to existing methods or you'd like to show only one new shipping method?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you a clear insight on what to do to determine if your method is available.

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

`collectCarrierRates()` is the function you need to adapt to your needs.